# multi threading in python (pythonwin hangs)

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

i am learning multi-threading in python and used following code from the following link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

The Pythonwin IDE hangs (not responding) for more than 30 min, Please help me if there is some problem in the code.

```
import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        time.sleep(delay)
        count += 1
        print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

    # Create two threads as follows
try:
    thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
    thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last code:

```
while 1:
   pass
```

It makes your code running forever ,so your ide won't response anymore.
If you want to wait these threads until run over,you can add `time.sleep(35)` at last to wait.

Answer (score 1):

The program will never finish.
Your program will write 5 times the data for each thread and then just hang forever on the main thread.